# How to change rectangle colour when user touches it

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-relativelayout

I place a rectangle on an Android screen by placing the drawable as the background for a `RelativeLayout`. The following is how I achieve it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/welcome_rectangle"
        android:id="@+id/rectangular_orange"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The following is the XML drawable for `welcome_rectangle`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green_welcome_rectangle" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/orange_welcome_rectangle" />
</selector>
```

I want the colour of the rectangle to change when the user touches it. This hasn't been achieved with the selector written. How can I change the selector code so that I can get what I want?

Comment: You probably should make your `RelativeLayout` clickable via `android:clickable="true"` attribute.

Comment: that's because your layout is not "[clickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable)"

Comment: Yes. The problem is the layout being unclickable. If someone posts this as an answer I'll choose it as an accepted one.